# Trying to access my json using $.getJson function of jquery

Tags: jquery, json, servlets, cross-domain, getjson

I am trying to access token from http://localhost:8090/appp/appp/getToken it returns me string with Content-Type:application/json on browser

I try to load this token using $.getJson from my wordpress application uploaded on url

http://localhost/wordpress/

but it does not return me that token

my code :

```
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:8090/appp/appp/getToken",
  {
 format: "json"
},
 function(token) {
 alert(token);
 });
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use jsonp since the domain is different from your page (due to the port number). The xhr request is considered cross domain and is falling foul of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

See the Additional Notes section from the jquery [getJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) docs

> Additional Notes: Due to browser
>   security restrictions, most "Ajax"
>   requests are subject to the same
>   origin policy; the request can not
>   successfully retrieve data from a
>   different domain, subdomain, or
>   protocol. Script and JSONP requests
>   are not subject to the same origin
>   policy restrictions.

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao Did you read what jsonp is and the requirements to support it? The endpoint needs to supports jsonp e.g return the json inside a javascript function.

Comment: @redsquare i added content-type:application/javascript in my servlet but it still does not return me :(

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao that is not enough. You cannot just return the json. It has to be wrapped inside the callback function e.g jsonp28383874374({success : false}) see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao This may help you also. Jsonp with wordpress http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/

Comment: @redsquare my return json is {"token":"6a978a36-8090-43df-8ee9-bf196a17c3ed%1ac75ba6-4d62-4083-ae8d-7d26a7ffdc5c"} and on client side i access it using data.token but still it does not return me :(

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao that is wrong you cannot just return the json. It has to be wrapped in a javascript function, please take the time to read my comments and the links I have attached.