# json - hot to retrieve data using json

Tags: javascript, json

My goal here is to retrieve the data from my server using json.
    when i run this code i got nothing.
    i don't know what i have done wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function fn_getdata()
            {
                $.getJSON("http://arvianne.com/android/index.php", function(data) {
                    alert(data.contacts);
                });
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="iddiv_con"></div>
    <button onclick="fn_getdata()">Get Data</button>
</body>
```

Comment: It might be because of same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy Can you share the domain name of the page which does the ajax request

Comment: how did i violate same origin policy? i'm using this "http://arvianne.com/android/index.php" address as dummy data.. should i delete this question?

Comment: I don't think you need to delete this, seems to be pretty valid question. What is the address of the page from where you are  sending the ajax request

Comment: i'm using localhost is that what you are asking? sorry dude i'm clueless... please guide me..

Comment: yes, then it is a violation of the same origin policy as the domain name of the page and the ajax request server are different, you can look at jsonp as a solution to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to access my json using $.getJson function of jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552188/trying-to-access-my-json-using-getjson-function-of-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your code is running in the `localhost` and you are trying to access a resource located at `arvianne.com` via `ajax`, you are in violation of the [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy) that is why your ajax request is not working.

If you monitor your ajax request using firebug/developer toolbar you can see an exception like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://arvianne.com/android/index.php. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`.

If possible you can look at [jsonp](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
You are violating the same origin policy
```

you should wrap your json in callback function.

use jsonp instead of simple json .

Answer (score 1):

Use firefox/firebug chrome/dev tools to monitor error messages - pound to a penny you're hitting a 'same origin' problem [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)